# Treating derivatives like a fraction.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So, for a cone filled with water, $V=\dfrac{\pi}{3} hr^2$ and you're given $\dfrac{dh}{dt}$ and $\dfrac{dr}{dt}$. Can you divide $\dfrac{dh}{dt}$ by $\dfrac{dr}{dt}$ to find $\dfrac{dh}{dr}$?

Comment: Yes.  This is called the chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the chain rule, you have $\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{dh}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}$, so solving for $\frac{dh}{dr}$ answers your question.